# how to rebuild without commit in Gitlab Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

Is there a way we can trigger another build manually without pushing another commit into merge request?

I'm using Jenkins and Gitlab integration

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitLab+Plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option in the "Configure" page of the Jenkins job for that (a recent addition I think).

Look for the textbox named:

`Comment (regex) for triggering a build`

Source:
http://blog.ljdelight.com/gitlab-trigger-jenkins-builds-on-merge-request/

Answer (score 2):

The regex-solution did not work in our setup, perhaps old/missing plugin in jenkins... But yesterday I found the best "solution"/hack (at least for me :-) ) by changing the **TARGET** branch of the merge request. Then I changed it back to the original one and a new pipeline startet without a senseless commit!